# Laravel Database Seeding: How to change the default name of the seeded column?

Tags: php, laravel

In the create_users_table I changed the name of the column from 'name' to 'username'. However while setting up the database seeder I get the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

This is the line in the DatabaseSeeder:
`$user = User::factory()->create();`

I tried changing the fillable property in the User model but still same problem. I do not know which file I should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for a file named:
`UserFactory.php`

it should be located at the path:
`\database\factories\`

if you cannot find it, I recommend checking for any other files with similar names in that directory.

To refresh the database migration:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

To seed the database:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

If you get an error during the migration process, you can try removing the `migrations` table and then re-running the migration command.

Please be aware that running the `php artisan migrate:refresh` command will indeed reset your database and remove all existing data.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.
You are right, the file that needed to be modified is `UserFactory.php` which had the line that populates the column in database named `name`. Modifying it solved the issue.
I also appreciate the knowledge provided about refreshing and seeding the database.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your database has the right column name and try to insert the full object in the seeder example:

```
DB:table('users')->insert([
'username'=> 'username',
'email' => 'myemail@email.pt',
'password' => Hash:make('mypassword')
]);
```

I am using [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries), but you can always do it [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent) and your models.

Comment: I appreciate your time and your answer. 
The issue was in the factory file that I failed to find. Modifying it fixed the problem.
I will keep your suggestion in mind in case I face a similar issue in the future!